# Access static property of component in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a

```
public $errorCode;
public static $errorMsg = array(
    100=>'Producto inexistente',
    101=>'Máximo de sesiones simultáneas alcanzado',
    102=>'No se pudo renovar la sesión',
    103=>'Sesión inexistente',
    104=>'No se pudo iniciar la sesión',
    105=>'No se pudo finalizar la sesión',
  );
```

in my Component.

I'm trying to access it this way:

`var_dump( Yii::app()->productSession->errorMsg );`

But will display `Undefined property`.

When I try `var_dump( Yii::app()->productSession::errorMsg );` I get unexpected `::`

Is it possible to access this property? If I let this `public` only it would work, I just don't want these strings populate memory in multiple instantiation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the $ :

```
var_dump( ProductSession::$errorMsg );
```

**EDIT**

Yep, sorry, :: is the operator for static members, so it does'nt fit on an instance : use the class name

Also check the PHP site, the case is well documented : 
[Static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: I still get unexpected :: for the 2nd, since that gets parsed first, anything beyond it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks It worked, though I don't want to use it now because I must use Class Name and not component's mapped name. Example: `SWCProductSession::$errorMsg`.

Comment: That's a design issue. Maybe you should use a function to retrieve your static array : public function errorMsg() { return self::$errorMsg; } I don't know what you're trying to achieve, so it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I used magic getter and that way I accomplised `var_dump( Yii::app()->productSession->errorMsg[ Yii::app()->productSession->errorCode ] )`